# React Native Manifest invalid character '-'

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-build

When I try to run `npm run android` command, I receive an error such:

AAPT: Tag  attribute package has invalid character '-'.

android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:18: AAPT: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24: AAPT: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

android/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2: Tag  attribute package has invalid character '-'.

app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:18: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'.

app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:24: Tag  attribute name has invalid character '-'

My AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test-native-app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.test-native-app.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test-native-app.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: It's obviously that change your app name `test-native-app` to some name doesn't have `-` will solve that error :)

Comment: Yeah, in the second I posted it I noticed that.. x ). Quite akward.

Comment: Using a hyphen is not a good practice, because it's an error. You have to change your app name. You can use underscore instead of hiphen.